# Convert grill recipe to convection toaster oven?

Tags: conversion

I generally just lower the temp 25 degrees when going from oven to the little convec toaster oven and it works out well.  This may be a silly question, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

I cook just about everything in there, since the oven seems like overkill when I'm cooking for two.

Comment: In tonight's case, the grilled eggplant recipe said:   Prepare your grill for high, direct heat. Make sure the grates are clean, and close the lid.

I ended up preheating to 400 and crossing my fingers.  Recipe called for 3-4 minutes per side, and 8 minutes worked fine (didn't seem necessary to flip them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion depends on what the recipe says to do for a grill.

If the recipe says to preheat the grill to high (for gas) or create two beds of charcoal under both halves (for charcoal), then preheat the broiler on your convection toaster oven and broil the food items on a rack set in a pan or on a grill insert.

If the recipe has a specific temperature, lower that by 25 degrees and use the convection cycle.

If the recipes doesn't give a specific temperature but instead suggests indirect grilling (where one side is higher and the food is on the low side or using a higher rack), use a lower temperature in your oven, perhaps 325, and cook as suggested.  That kind of recipe will probably take the most trial and error.

Comment: I appreciate it!  I'm getting more adventurous, and I'm hoping tips like this will decrease my chances of creating inedible lumps.